# SQL Select statement - base results upon the value of an alias within statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a Select statement (comprised of around 20 different joined aliases) that will only return results if the value of one of the aliases created within the same statement equals a certain value.

I'm very green with SQL at this point and therefore don't really know how to phrase this dilemma properly to find the answer elsewhere.

Current code for element being assigned an alias of "cmp_freq":

```
ISNULL((SELECT GroupValue FROM ClientGroup WHERE ClientKey = c.ClientKey AND GroupCode = 'CMP-FREQ'),'PLEASE UPDATE FIELD') AS cmp_freq
```

Essentially, I only want results returned for the entire statement where the value of cmp_freq is "30".  Is there any way to reference this alias in the where clause of the statement as a whole in order to accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish your goal.  One way would be to wrap your query in a `SELECT` and use a `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
SELECT i.cmp_freq
FROM (
        /* Your existing query */
        SELECT
        ISNULL((SELECT GroupValue FROM ClientGroup WHERE ClientKey = c.ClientKey AND GroupCode = 'CMP-FREQ'),'PLEASE UPDATE FIELD') AS cmp_freq
        FROM MyTable c
    ) i
WHERE i.cmp_freq = 30
```

It's difficult to offer other options as there is not enough information in your question.